# SQL 2005 won't fully uninstall

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to uninstall my default instance of SQL Server 2005 from my Windows 7 machine but having a few problems. Everything uninstalls as it should using Add/Remove programs but for some reason I am still left with the `SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)` service installed and have no way of getting rid of it.

I have tried to reinstall SQL Server 2005 and uninstall, followed the following Microsoft kb article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967  which uses the `ARPWrapper.exe /Remove` switch, but still the service exists. I want to get rid of every service so I can start with a clean install of named instances of SQL2005 and SQL2008.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SU is better than SF for kind of questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If getting rid of the SSRS service is the only thing that needs to be done, you can use the sc.exe utility:

- [How to Remove an Unwanted Service in Windows 7/Vista/XP](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-remove-an-unwanted-service/)
- [Windows XP documentation for sc.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true)